# How can I attach the same footprint to subparts of the same IC in Altium?

Tags: altium, layout, footprint

I have two sub parts of the same IC (STM32L476RG). [image]

I have added these sub parts as two components in the same schematic library and have attached the same footprints for both of them. But when I make the layout, I get two separate footprints for them. How do I make sure that both these subparts are recognised as parts of the same IC? I am using Altium designer tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create separate parts in the library. Altium provides you with the ability to create sub-parts (multi-part components). This is popular for large ICs (i.e. FPGAs, or ICs with multiple independent functions), or ICs such as digital logic where you might have multiple identical gates in a single component.

You can find a description of how to do this in the [Altium documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/1.1/display/NEXUS/((A+Look+at+Creating+Library+Components))_AD). Scroll down to where it says `Creating a New Schematic Component with Multiple Parts`.

Effectively, you start by creating a new component (just the first part). When that's done go to the `Tools` menu and select `New Part`. Alternatively you can use the shortcut `T-W`.

[image]

From there you can create your second sub-part, and repeat the "New Part" process as many times as you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your schematic library, create your first sub-part
2. then go to Tools >> Add Part
3. Make second sub-part here and add your footprint
4. Compile and done!

Comment: Step "4." is optional and dependent on your library structure.  If using a native schlib (not intlibs or other complexities), then simply saving the schlib library is adequate.